# Get Steam Market (API) results in euro

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steambot

I use this URL to get 100 results at a time of CS:GO containers. I substitute `{currency}` for `3` and `{start}` for a multiple of 100, my problem is that `currency=3` doesn't seem to be euro, it is about 17% off (I have to multiply received value by 0.83 to get a pretty good result):

```py
market_url = ("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?"
    "category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_WeaponCase"
    "&norender=1"
    "&count=100"
    "&sort_column=name"
    "&sort_dir=asc"
    "&currency={currency}"
    "&start={start}")
```

From what I understand:

- `category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_WeaponCase` is to choose CS:GO crates
- `norender=1` is to not get html
- `count=100` - results per page
- `sort_column=name&sort_dir=asc` for ordering
- `currency=3` choose euro as currency <-- doesn't work
- `start=100` start at result 100

But however, I change the currency it doesn't change `sell_price` nor `sell_price_text` in response. It still prints:

`(...) "sell_listings":68,"sell_price":963,"sell_price_text":"9,63€" (...)` Note the €.

Do I have a typo there? Is `currency` even parsed on the steam part?

To be crystal clear. I would like to get the same price (in euros) as is presented on the [steam market](https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_WeaponCase&appid=730) (if you have the site in euros).

**EDIT:** Seems impossible at the moment. **If it becomes possible, please post a new answer!**

Comment: Do you want it to be in Euros or not?

Comment: @JackSparrow Yes, I would like to get the results in euros. Specifically, I would like to get the same results (price in euros) you would get on steam market https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_WeaponCase&appid=730 I edited the post to clarify, thanks!

Comment: Be sure to include parameter `l`to be set according to language you want to be. Taking the URL you posted above in comment, I modified it to be `https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_ProPlayer%5B%5D=any&category_730_StickerCapsule%5B%5D=any&category_730_TournamentTeam%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&category_730_Type%5B%5D=tag_CSGO_Type_WeaponCase&appid=730&norender=1&l=english` to get all the results.

Comment: in every search page you want, you can add `/render` to  `https://steamcommunity.com/market/search` page so working URL looks like `https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render` and you specify params like `norender=1`and `l=english` to get results in english, note that steam automatically determines locale and currency based on browser locale and shows prices automatically in that currency.

Comment: @JackSparrow I don't really think this will get me closer to displaying the steam community market in euros though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Get Steam Market (API) results in euro

Unfortunately, it isn't possible. The parameter you're referring to, i.e. `currency` only allows for specific sub-pages to be called, e.g.:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=Fracture%20Case
```

*(looking for the price of the Fracture Case)* - returns:

> {"success":true,"lowest_price":"0,39€","volume":"84,984","median_price":"0,39€"}

If you change `currency` to be equal to `1` (being dollar):

> {"success":true,"lowest_price":"$0.49","volume":"84,847","median_price":"$0.48"}

As you can clearly see, `currency` works perfectly fine with `https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/`.

---

Though as far as I'm aware, `https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?` doesn't take the `currency` parameter as an input, i.e. the currency will ultimately be rendered as dollar (or `currency=1`).

What you could do is to scrape via `https://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?` and looking up the price via `https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?`, though this option will yield pretty inaccurate results (`priceoverview` only displays a limited amount of details).

---

On a slight off-topic note: You can convert the price locally (with other APIs or for static currency pairs with a certain factor). Though as you specifically mentioned that you want to do it via the official price (calculating it "manually" ends up with differences, steam-related) that isn't a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and my only solution was including my cookies to the request so steam knows my login and automatically sends prices in my default currency.

```
"Cookie":  
    "steamMachineAuthXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; "
    "Steam_Language=english; "
    "steamLoginSecure=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX||XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; "
```

Note: I changed the actual values to "X" for security reasons.